# does anyone knows good ajax script loader

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Does anyone knows ajax script loader that allows lazy loading of js and css files and also consist of dependency list that can be defined in external script?

Comment: What do you mean with "lazy loading of js ?" ?

Comment: @genesis: I'm guessing he means only to load a JS file if it's required, for example a set of thumbnails may be loaded and then require "fancybox" support, then the relevant JS/CSS/images can be loaded as required.

Comment: aha. Su just add it into <sript src="...."></script> in ajax loaded page. or not?

Comment: @genesis: Marcel explanation is exactly what I ment. I can't just add it to the <script> tag because the user may not use this option. Morover, I want to manage dependencies list because I don't want to remember what are the dependency for each plugin in the page.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use http://unwrongest.com/projects/lazy/ ?

Comment: Noar: I think yes because it's aimed to jquery

Comment: Its a jQuery Plugin so you have to use jQuery. Well but i dont understand your question completely, what do you mean with good for jquery users?

Comment: @Daniel Ruf: What I asked is does this package fits only if I use jquery? Can I use this package without jquery?

Comment: you have to use the javascript framework jquery because its a jquery plugin

Answer (score 1):

In my various projects I use [LABjs](http://labjs.com/). Easy and flexible :)

Comment: Can I define dependencies list in LABjs?

Answer (score 1):

If you need a smart why to load or skip resources, see http://yepnopejs.com/ :

> yepnope is an asynchronous conditional
>   resource loader that's super-fast, and
>   allows you to load only the scripts
>   that your users need.

[Modrnizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) is a good example of yepnoejs usage.

Comment: Can I define dependencies list in yepnoejs?

Comment: @Naor: I do not see any smart built in dependency features in yepnopejs.  However: 1: `On top of all that, inside of your array, each item can be a test object, another array, or a string literal...`, so you can create a master object with your requirements.  2. You  can use the callbacks and the complete event, look for `What happens if I use yepnope inside of a yepnope callback?`. 3: You can probably further load stuff from within loaded scripts, although this is not optimal in many ways.

Answer (score 1):

Just include

```
<script src="your_lazy.js"></script>
```

in script (html) which is loaded with your ajax-called page

Comment: The script doesn;t need to hold the paths of the scripts they need.